# Postgres - Add a column to a table with a default value, but set existing rows to a different default value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to add a boolean column to a table and have the default value be false for newly created rows, but all existing rows should be set to true. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First alter table and add column as
`alter table table_name add column column_name boolean default false;`

Then update value of that column as

`update table_name set column_name=true;`

Answer (score 0):

A simplified test to demonstrate.

> ```
> create table test (
>  id int primary key
> );
>
> insert into test (id) values (1), (2), (3);
> ```

> ```
> alter table test 
>  add column truth boolean default false;
>
> update test set truth = true;
> ```

> ```
> insert into test (id) values (4), (5);
> ```

> ```
> select * from test;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | truth
> -: | :----
>  1 | t    
>  2 | t    
>  3 | t    
>  4 | f    
>  5 | f
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a570b27f7a0f97b2073aaa76a2868e5b)*